# noscript not applying CSS until you click Refresh button

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm using `noscript` to display a banner at the top of the page if a user has javascript disabled. It is similar to the one SO used when your browser's JS is disabled.

My problem, if you visit the page, it displays the `noscript` raw text with no `CSS` styles applied. If you hit F5 or click the refresh button, then suddenly the `CSS` applies and the warning gets the correct red background and bold larger text.

Why is this happening? I'm getting this behavior in Chrome (latest) and IE10... as well as old IE8 and FireFox 3.x series.

Here's my `noscript` tag which is in the body of the page:

```
<noscript><div id="noscript-frame">Website.com works best with JavaScript enabled</div></noscript>
```

`CSS` looks like:

```
#noscript-frame{
    background-color: #AE0000;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-style: normal;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    font-family: "Verdana", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: center;
}
```

When you first load the page, it ends up looking like this with no styles applied, just raw text:

```
Website.com works best with JavaScript enabled
```

when you refresh the page, then it applies the styles and everything looks good.

Any ideas how I can fix this? I tried having the `div` populated without using the `noscript` tag and then having javascript hide it's contents upon page load, but this causes the infamous screen flicker on page load...

Comment: It seems as though the page is being cached.

Comment: @JoshC even when it's fresh visited by the browser? i've tried on several of the machines around the office, most of which don't visit our development website, and therefore shouldn't have this page cached already... ?

Comment: I've copied your code as posted here and it works fine for me in Firefox. [Here is my version.](http://gutfullofbeer.net/ns.html) However, it fails as you describe in Chrome.

Comment: @Pointy thanks for the 3rd party verification ;-P  -- I get exactly the same behavior on your example as what I'm seeing, including the sometimes displaying the `<div>` tag along with the raw text. Is there a work-around for this behavior? I'm seeing it not just in Chrome unfortunately, otherwise I'd say it's ok as is since most of our website traffic is still IE users (of course).

Comment: The behavior is weird; in my opinion it's a Chrome (or WebKit) bug, clearly. It's *really* strange that IE has the problem too. I don't know of any workaround; personally I handle the "no JavaScript" case with a `<meta>` tag inside `<noscript>` to redirect to a whole different page.

Comment: @Pointy maybe it's just my environment that's causing IE to have the same issue (firewall, loadbalancer, etc). It very well could be a WebKit bug. That would be very unfortunate since so many browsers use or are based on webkit.